# Altruist badge description link to bounty

Tags: feature-request, badges, bounties

Would it be possible to include a link to "bounty" (https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) on the Altruist badge?

This would be helpful to a new user that's just learning about badges as Altruist is right at the top of the list of badges.

I guess for that matter, it could be applied to any place "bounty" shows up in badge descriptions (Altruist, Benefactor, Investor & Promoter).